# incorrect date value error in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, stored-procedures

**My request payload from the client javascript/angular**

```
active: 1
appId: "asdf"
description: "asdf"
from: "06/16/2015"
name: "gdsfg"
to: "06/18/2015"
```

**Node.js code is**

```
var query = "SET @start = '" + request.body.from  + "'; \
                         SET @end = '" + request.body.to + "'; \
                         SET @event_id = " + rows.insertId + "; \
                         CALL day(@start, @end, @event_id);";
```

**Error return is**

```
{ [Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect date value: '06/16/2015' for column 'start' at row 2]
  code: 'ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE',
  errno: 1292,
  sqlState: '22007',
  index: 3 }
```

**stored procedure:**

(in essence it takes the from and to dates and create the number of rows based on the difference).

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `day`(start DATE, end DATE, event_id INT)
BEGIN
    WHILE start <= end DO
        INSERT INTO day(date, event_id) VALUES(start, event_id);
        SET start = start + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

**Question:**

not sure what's causing the error, can anyone please help

Edit - query output

```
SET @start = '06/16/2015'; SET @end = '06/18/2015'; SET @event_id = 3; CALL day(@start, @end, @event_id);
```

Comment: What do `start` and `end` look like?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that `date` is stored as a date.  But `start` is not, possibly it is just an integer that *looks* like a date.

If so, this will fix your problem:

```
WHILE start <= end DO
    INSERT INTO day(date, event_id) VALUES(start, event_id);
    SET start = date_add(@tart, interval 1 day);
END WHILE;
```

EDIT:

That is not the problem.  The problem is in the calling code.  So try:

```
var query = "SET @start = str_to_date('" + request.body.from  + "', '%m/%d/%Y'); \
                         SET @end = str_to_date('" + request.body.to + "', '%m/%d/%Y'); \
                         SET @event_id = " + rows.insertId + "; \
                         CALL day(@start, @end, @event_id);";
```

Comment: it used to work fine with the `start = start + 1`, I did apply your `date_add` method but still the same error

Comment: Change your date formats to YYYY-MM-DD format, so '2015-06-16' and '2015-05-18'.

Comment: it's american, they expect to see MM-DD--YYYY, it does solve the problem though, I wonder why it used to work before,

Comment: The ISO standard and the standard for MySQL is YYYY-MM-DD.  Try using that format to see if it works.  If it does, then use format the user input to create an appropriate date format for the database.

Comment: can you please add some date_format code in the stored procedure query, date is going to come as `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: I wonder how mysql checks a date and figures out the month or date, what if I pass `01-01-2015', 01 maybe month may be date

Comment: my attempt, modified sql a bit `INSERT INTO day(date, event_id) VALUES(DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%M-%d'), event_id);` but :(

Comment: You may need to put that logic into the `call` statement rather than inside the stored procedure.  That seems to be where (at least) one error arises.

Comment: also the stored procedure works without @ symbols, is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

you should use **'yyyy-mm-dd'** format instead of **'mm/dd/yyyy'** in your query. as your procedure parameters are date type

your query should be like this

```
SET @start = '2015-06-16'; SET @end = '2015-06-18'; SET @event_id = 3; CALL day(@start, @end, @event_id);
```